# Partially correct on codeeval

Tags: c++

**This is my answer to a codeeval solution. Shows Partially correct. Cannot figure out why.**

https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/18/ this is the question.
Will be glad for the help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    if(!infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error:Cannot open file!";
        cout << "Program terminating.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    string line;
    while(getline(infile, line, '\n'))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string token;

        getline(ss,token,',');
            long x = stoi(token);

        getline(ss, token, ',');
            long n = stoi(token);

            while(n < x)
            {
                n <<= 1;
            }
            cout << n << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume "smallest multiple of n" doesn't just mean following powers of two. Try `int mul=1; while(n*mul < x){mul++;} cout << n*mul << '\n';`

Comment: I tried that both ways. Initially instead of (n <<= 1) i had written (n += n).

Comment: ok, wenn maybe it wants you to check whether the second input is a power of two first.

Comment: @SChepurin it's the inverse of "smallest multiple of n which is greater than or equal to x"

Comment: @PeterT - "multiple of n". not "n".

Comment: @SChepurin he mutated n, what difference does it make?

Comment: @Peter - yes.My mistake.

Comment: @generic2709 the issue may be with `getline(ss,token,',');` the second one should `be getline(ss,token);`

Comment: @PeterT - it must concern only the calculation part. I guess. And seems that calculation is correct.

Comment: @PeterT The (,) is the delimiter. I cannot use getline(ss, token) it will change the output.

Comment: If you guys read the problem, It says that two numbers are entered and the second is a power of 2 so i don't have to check that. Calculation is right either ways.

Comment: @generic2709 - Out of curiosity i checked the solution. The problem is that your solution results in error. But simple n *= 2; produces the Partially correct result (20 points). Try to analyse from this point.

Comment: @PeterT i took that (,) out no differece.

Comment: @Schepurin- It runs fine on my compiler. gives out the right result.

Comment: I still don't get it. So what needs to be done?

Comment: @generic2709 - Finally. The task is solved (but with calculation in the form - "n*=2"). Then, you see Partially solved message and should receive an e-mail saying that you solved challenge which is a part of complex set of tasks with 4 more to solve - File Size,Odd Numbers,Sum of Integers and Number Pairs. Hope i got it right.

Comment: But the question clearly prohibits the use of * or %. Anyways i am going to let this slide. Can't keep thinking  about this. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @generic2709 - It says "Do not use division or modulo operator". And i take it literally. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming#Overview)- "...some contest problems may allow for partial scoring, depending on the number of test cases passed...". Anyway, if you still think it sounds unbelievably dumb, solve one of the proposed tasks and see if message will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in much easier way.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,n;
    cin>>x >>n;
    while( n < x)
        n *= 2;
    cout<<n<<"\n":
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's wrong, the task specifies `greater than or equal to`, also what's the advantage of doing the if and the while?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have edited the code. Please let me know if you find anything wrong.

Comment: The problem is to read from a file. It needs to be tokenized and then then condition can be checked.

Comment: @Shravan40 - that seems to be okay, but they evaluate reading from CSV file also.